# retain input value on submit/reload from input created from associative array (No Jquery/Javascript)

Tags: php, forms, input, submit, associative-array

Student here. I'm taking a class in php, and i have to do everything using php, not jQuery or javascript (not complaining, just how it is with the class I am taking - it's very cool and i am greatly enjoying it).

I am working on student php application which when i'm done will use data scraping to access this weeks new comic book releases and store them in an associative array which will then be looped through to create a series of inputs (number) to allow a user to specify how many of each comic they would like to order. Then i'll do some math to show the user the subtotal, tax, and the total, and ask them to confirm or to revise their order. This is a student project, i am a student. This is not a real world use case, but a training lesson.

The problem i'm finding is that on submit, i'm not able to populate the input values so that someone can see what they ordered/what their order value is should they want to 'revise' it and resubmit the order before confirming it.

var_dumps show that i have the value, i just can't get the value to repopulate/display in it's respective input field after doing a post back submit. The problem to me seems to be with the " . $_POST['valueName']  . ". As each input is generated from an associative array, i've no foreknowledge of what the name will be so i can not simply do "$_POST['valueName']", instead i must do something like "$_POST['$var']", but this doesn't work as it's done via concatenation. Hopefully someone out there has an idea of how i can best tackle this.

Again - i am a student, so please assume i know nothing -  Thank you all for looking
cheers!

This is my test array:

```
<?php
    // My test array
    $newRelease = [
        'All-New Wolverine #7' => '3.99',
        'Captain America Omnibus Volume 1 HC (New Printing)' => '125.00',
        'Amazing Spider-Man #11' => '3.99',
        'Daredevil #6 (David Lopez Story Thus Far Variant Cover)' => 'AR',
        'Doctor Strange #7 (Chris Bachalo Regular Cover)' => '3.99',
    ];


    /*
     * Loop thru array, create inputs which populate
     * when submitted based on post values
     * PHP course - can't use javascript/jquery - must be PHP

    foreach ($newRelease as $title => $price) {
    echo $title . ' - ' . $price .  ' (ea.) <input type="text" name="' . $title . '" value="' . $_POST[$title] . '" > <br /> -- ' . $check . ' -- <br/><br />';
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem:**

> The problem i'm finding is that on submit, i'm not able to populate the input values so people can see what ordered should they want to change them once they see the total.

**Solution:**

In each iteration of `foreach` loop, check whether `$_POST['YOUR_FIELD_NAME']` is set or not. If it's set then display the user submitted value i.e `$_POST['YOUR_FIELD_NAME']`, otherwise display the predefined array value `price`.

```
<?php

    $newRelease = [
        'All-New Wolverine #7' => '3.99',
        'Captain America Omnibus Volume 1 HC (New Printing)' => '125.00',
        'Amazing Spider-Man #11' => '3.99',
        'Daredevil #6 (David Lopez Story Thus Far Variant Cover)' => 'AR',
        'Doctor Strange #7 (Chris Bachalo Regular Cover)' => '3.99',
    ];
    ?>
    <form action="index.php" method="POST">
    <?php
    foreach ($newRelease as $title => $price){
        $title = str_replace(' ', '_', $title);
        ?>
        <input type="text" name="<?php echo $title; ?>" value="<?php if(isset($_POST[$title])){ echo $_POST[$title]; }else{ echo $price; } ?>" ><br />
        <?php
    }
    ?>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
    </form>
    <?php

?>
```

**Why did I use `str_replace()` function?**

You cannot use dot or space in input field names. From [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.external.php):

> **Dots and spaces in variable names are converted to underscores**. For example  becomes $_REQUEST["a_b"].

So you have to use `str_replace()` function to replace all white spaces with underscores so that `$_POST` could detect the user submitted value. If you want to see the contents of `$_POST` superglobal, do `var_dump($_POST);`.

Comment: Thank you for the notes - they feel very excessiblef and I look forward to continuing my project with your suggestions. You help is very much appreciated - thank you!

Comment: @Chezshire Glad I could help. *Cheers!* :-)

Comment: HI So i just tested this, and it wasn't 'quite' the answer i needed as i wanted to show/retain the value of the number of issues ordered. But with a simple tweak, it does as i want, plus it lets me see other ways of using it. This was a really really educational answer and I really wanted to thank you for it. It was so amazingly understandable and I really really appreciate the help Rajdeep!

Comment: Thanks for the appreciation. Happy coding. :-)